# Android Spinner selected value read from Firebase child value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an `EditProfile` activity and this is to be used **to edit user's home address**.

This is my Firebase childsnapshot:

[image]

And this is my `EditProfile` snapshot:

[image]

Problem: I want to make the "State" spinner to show the value directly that same as the child userState value. May I know how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I had tried .getText().toString() but it failed to fetch. (Maybe getText is for EditText only?)

Comment: Please share the code and indicate what exactly doesn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to select the data on your spinner.

```
 if(state != null) {
     for (int j = 0; j <= stateSpinner.getCount(); j++) {
         if (stateSpinner.getItemAtPosition(j).equals(state)) {
             stateSpinner.setSelection(j);
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

Here,
stateSpinner is the variable name for spinner and state is the fetched data from Firebase.

Comment: Thanks! Your code is working for my case!